# Common class library deployment woes

Tags: deployment

I've moved some common code into a class library for my SharePoint Feature.
I added it to the feature dependencies, I fooled with the package to make sure that the DLL is deployed correctly.  I marked everything as 'WebApplication' deployment.

Everything compiles correctly, but when I go to deploy it...

> Error occurred in deployment step
>   'Activate Features': Could not load
>   file or assembly 'SPSureCommon,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=6422b3acc455bdc9' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

Can any one tell me how to troubleshoot this?  I mean, IF it actually deployed and crashed at runtime I could at least feature out what DLL is missing.

[image: Package]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check the GAC (C:\windows\assembly), is your dll there?

If it is, check that the token/version is the same as the one your a referencing in code.

Also, you might be deploying to a different web application, do a full IIS reset

If the DDL isn't in the GAC, then there is something wrong with your package.

Check the pkg/pkgobj directories to see if the dll is there, also open up the wsp (rename to cab) and check it is inside.

Try activating though central admin

Comment: I was trying to be a good citizen and keep everything in the web application folder.  That said, I was able to get it to work if I put this single library in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Double click your Package folder and Add the assembly from a the appropriate option (file or project output)

Once you have that referenced you should be able to deploy no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to see what is going on.

Comment: I couldn't get the Fusion log view to show me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Set deployment target to GAC and see if it works. Might be another issue somewhere else.